# What does かけまいと mean here?

Tags: meaning

お前、心配かけまいと無理してるんじゃないだろうな

From what I can understand from this is probably

"You aren't doing anything unreasonable right?"

How does the 心配 (worry) fit in here ?

I understand that
Verb dictionary form + まい = denial/negative

However this is not a dictionary form so how does is work here

Comment: For 一段 verbs まい goes after the 連用形 instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「お前{まえ}、心配{しんぱい}**かけまい**と無理{むり}してるんじゃないだろうな。」

「かけまいと」 means 「かけないように」.

> I understand that Verb dictionary form + まい = denial/negative.

Your understanding is only half-correct.  The verb form that can precede 「まい」　depends on the type of verb.

> Type I: ***Dictionary form*** of a 五（四）段 verb & subsidiary verb 「ます」
>
> Type II: ***Imperfective form*** of a 上一段・下一段・カ行変格・サ行変格 verb & subsidiary verbs 「れる・られる」 and 「せる・させる」.

「かける」 is a 下一段 verb, so you need to use its imperfective form 「かけ」 to attach 「まい」 to it.

> "**You're not overstraining yourself, trying not to cause me to worry, are you?**"

Other examples:

Type I: あるまい、言うまい、行くまい、話すまい、戻るまい

Type II: させまい、されまい、しまい、もらえまい、くれまい

NOTE: "Type I" and "Type II" are the names I just created for the purpose of answering this question.