# だろうと how can I translate it?

Tags: particle-と, volitional-form

I am reading *The Little Prince* in Japanese and I am not sure about how to translate だろうと in the following sentence:

> 大人たちにそう言われてから、今度はわかってくれる**だろうと**ウワバミの中身を描いて見ました。

I don't know how to literally translate it, even if I understand the meaning of the sentence...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This と is the quotative-と. `volition/inference + と` can be used without any explicit following verb, and it means "thinking ...", "trying ...", "hoping ..." or such. だろう is part of the "quote."

> 今度はわかってくれるだろうと
>   =「今度はわかってくれるだろう」と**思って**
>   = ..., thinking/hoping (adults) will understand (the picture) this time, ...

Similar questions:

- [Volitional + と in ひとまず心を落ち着けようと、[...]](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13441/5010)
- [Meaning of と in 友蔵が出おくれまいと言いそえた](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42287/5010)
- [Embedded question followed by と](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25361/5010)
- [What does かけまいと mean here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45086/5010)